# Defintive article "the" in a sentence containing "national consciousness"

Tags: grammaticality

In a recent written assignment I used the following sentence:

> The practice of wearing a face covering has become a part of the
> national consciousness.

On submission, it was pointed out that "the" ought not to be used here. But this (the absence of "the") sounds intuitively wrong to me, and various searches on the topic have not resolved the matter in my mind.

I'd be grateful for any insight into which form is correct.

Comment: Are your critics native English speakers? Either one is okay, but I think it’s best with *the.* Search Ngram for “* national interest” and look at what you get to provide you with some evidence.

Comment: What @Xanne said. [Here's the relevant NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=part+of+national+consciousness%2Cpart+of+the+national+consciousness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpart%20of%20national%20consciousness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpart%20of%20the%20national%20consciousness%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***part of national consciousness*** is significantly less common than the version ***with*** an article. But it's certainly not ***uncommon***.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I wasn't aware of NGram, but that will be a valuable resource in the future, and bears out what I suspected. The correction was made by someone who is not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd only say it with "the." I think they're saying that without "national" beforehand, we often don't say "the" before "consciousness," which is true, but in this case, they're wrong.

"The" being used as a determiner is necessary in the given context since "consciousness" isn't being used to mean awareness of one's own existence, sensations, and thoughts but is being used to mean the thoughts and feelings, collectively, of an individual or of an aggregate of people. In the former, we use "consciousness" as a noncount noun and so don't put "the" beforehand, but in the latter, we do. See the link below and example under definition 2:

> [consciousness](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consciousness) [ kon-shuhs-nis ]
>
> noun
>
> 1. the state of being conscious; awareness of one's own existence, sensations, thoughts, surroundings, etc.
> 2. the thoughts and feelings, collectively, of an individual or of an aggregate of people:
>    **the moral consciousness of a nation.**

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you for the detailed explanation and the link. I don't have enough reputation to mark this as a "useful answer", but I have set it as the accepted solution.